# ¿Problema para desplegar datos en el datatable?

Tags: php, ajax, pdo, datatable

Estimado tengo un problema con el datatable me sale un error TypeError: aData is undefined creo que tiene que ser que el arreglo lo esta llamando como  "data": [.Creo que ese es el problema. si alguien me puede echar una mano se lo agradecería mucho

#Estimado este es el html donde estoy trabajando con datatable. tiene su html y su respectivo script

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no">
    <title> MAX </title>
      
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.11.5/css/jquery.dataTables.css">
  <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf8" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.js"></script>


</head>
<body>

    





<table id="example" class="display" style="width:100%">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th></th>
                <th>Name</th>
                <th>Position</th>
                <th>Office</th>
                <th>Salary</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
      
    </table>



    <script type="text/javascript">
/* Formatting function for row details - modify as you need */
function format ( d ) {
    // `d` is the original data object for the row
    return '<table cellpadding="5" cellspacing="0" border="0" style="padding-left:50px;">'+
        '<tr>'+
            '<td>Full name:</td>'+
            '<td>'+d.total_valor_combustible+'</td>'+
        '</tr>'+
        '<tr>'+
            '<td>Extension number:</td>'+
            '<td>'+d.litro_combustible+'</td>'+
        '</tr>'+
        '<tr>'+
            '<td>Extra info:</td>'+
            '<td>And any further details here (images etc)...</td>'+
        '</tr>'+
    '</table>';
}

$(document).ready(function() {
    var table = $('#example').DataTable( {
         "processing": true,
        "ajax": "Mostrar_Combustible.php",
       "columns": [
          {
                "className":      'dt-control',
                "orderable":      false,
                "data":           null,
                "defaultContent": ''
            },
            { "data": "id_combustible" },
            { "data": "empresa_compra_combustible" },
            { "data": "fecha_compra_combustible" },
            { "data": "numero_factura_combustible" }
        ],
        "order": [[1, 'asc']]
    } );
     
    // Add event listener for opening and closing details
    $('#example tbody').on('click', 'td.dt-control', function () {
        var tr = $(this).closest('tr');
        var row = table.row( tr );
 
        if ( row.child.isShown() ) {
            // This row is already open - close it
            row.child.hide();
            tr.removeClass('shown');
        }
        else {
            // Open this row
            row.child( format(row.data()) ).show();
            tr.addClass('shown');
        }
    } );
} );

    </script>

<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf8" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.11.5/js/jquery.dataTables.js"></script>



</body>
</html>
```

#Este codigo es donde llamo los datos de la bbdd que quiero que se desplegué en el datatable. Al parecer creo que tengo que dejarlo  "data": así para que me pueda mostrar los datos en datatable. porque lo estoy enviando como object

```
<?php

 require("../Conexion/base.php");
    $sentencia =("SELECT id_combustible,empresa_compra_combustible,fecha_compra_combustible,numero_factura_combustible, total_valor_combustible ,litro_combustible FROM combustible ORDER BY id_combustible DESC");
       $data = $base->query($sentencia)->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);


echo json_encode( array('Data'=>$data) );

?>
```

Comment: Intente agregar esto: `"sAjaxDataProp": "data"` en su petición Ajax, así reconocerá el nodo `data` como respuesta.

Comment: O, si está buscando la respuesta en `aData` puede hacer algo así: `echo json_encode( array('aData'=>$data) );` y quitar lo sugerido en el anterior comentario.

Comment: @A.Cedano encontre el error gracias estimado